# facebook cognito android example not working

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-cognito

I have implemented facebook android cognito example cognitosyncdemo as per the instructions, i am getting following error, when trying sync the dataset,

E/ListDatasetsActivity(8541): Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value '{graph.facebook.com=}' at 'logins' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 2048, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\S]+

Note: The code is exactly as per the example cognitodemosync.  from github

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to spend too much time on that example. It is very simple. Use Facebook SDK to get an access token then pass that token to Cognito. Job Done!
Instead of going after the the already created example, Create your own project.
include facebook sdk, AWS Core SDK, AWS provider SDK and AWS Cognito SDK. Then in the first activity, connect to facebook and get the user authorized. Successful authorization will provide an access token. Send that access token to Cognito to create Identity after adding the key value pair (key:'graph.facebook.com' and value: 'accessToken') to the CredentialProvider.
I hope the answer is clear.

Comment: In that case, the user is not registered in the user pool. Can you please guide me to how to add social login user add in user pool?